# Open Google Play page of my app, with navigation/search features disabled

Tags: java, android, google-play, launcher

I am developing an app with launcher features (which is also Device Admin). In my app there is a button which when pressed opens the Google Play listing for my app so that users can update to the latest version. I am using the below code to achieve this :

```
try {
    final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); 
    try {
         startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
         startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    }
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Everything works fine, no problem here. Upon excecution of above code, the user is presented with this (pardon the Greek):

[image]

Due to the fact that my app should function as a launcher (in the sense that it shouldn't allow other apps to launch, and especially other launcher apps) the back button and search field pose a risk for me. In theory the user could navigate or search and download some other app other than my own as presented bellow:

[image]

So, my question is, **is there a way to launch the Google Play listing of my app without the back button and search bar/icon?** A page where the user can perform actions regarding my app and nothing more. No way to install other apps.

If someone comes up with an alternate approach which produces the same results, then by all means share your wisdom! But *a Google Play listing of my app without the navigation/search bar on top* would be the Holy Grail for me at this point! :D

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance.

*Some answers to anticipated questions. (Users that feel they have already read enough need not go past this point):*

1. The app is targeted torwards a **very specific demographic**. It is a tool for bus drivers to print tickets using a thermal printer over Bluetooth and perform various work related tasks. The devices are not the drivers' personal devices but devices provided by their agency as work tools. The launcher features try to address an issue where drivers would consume their monthly mobile data using apps like Youtube e.t.c.
2. I have a **Whitelist** of apps that the user can freely launch. There is a **service** that checks which is the current app on the foreground and if it does not belong to the Whitelist, it immediately redirects the user back to my app (as there is no legit way to kill those apps on a non-rooted device). **The problem with this approach** is that if the app that was launced is a **launcher app** (let's say Nova Launcher) , then in the milliseconds that this launcher app was in the foreground before the service redirected the user back to my app, the launcher app had already presented the user with a dialog to pick the prefered launcher app for the device like the one below, thus disabling my app and gaining free access accross the device :

[image]

Comment: Google play does not support this feature. But as a device admin, your app probably could update itself without user interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in-app-updates to give updates to your app(but this **supports API 21 and above**)

> Supporting API level 21 and above, the Play Core library now allows us to offer in-app updates to our users — meaning we can show that an app update is available whilst the user is within the context of our application

If your app satisfies the API level(ie minimum SDK is 21) follow this [guideline](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates) to use in-app-updates

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer. To use in-app-updates my app should use a signed Android App Bundle instead of a signed APK, correct ?

Comment: It works with both Android App Bundle and signed APK

Comment: I followed your suggestion and implemented the in-app-updates instead of browsing Google Play. It seems to work really well, hence i will now upvote and accept your answer! Thank you!